# Failed to run aapt dump badging:AndroidManifest.xml is corrupt

Tags: android, xml

I am new to android.

i get this error when i try to upload update of my app to google play.

```
Failed to run aapt dump badging:W/ResourceType(19538): Bad resource table: header size 0x708b or total size 0x2f2432a is larger than data size 0x1ce1c
```

ERROR: AndroidManifest.xml is corrupt

i tried ALMOST VERYTHING google fixes.but nothing works.

please help.
It gave me that 'uploading in debuggable mode' thiny too but i managed to fix it.

sorry about my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same problem recently (with the very similar error message) and I also had a lot of trouble to solve, but finally I got it like this:

1. I used the PhoneGap Builder to generate the APK (so I recommend using the same one); Remembering that to test manages the APK with the same blank key (it's the default markup);
2. After generating, I used Apk-Signer (https://shatter-box.com/knowledgebase/android-apk-signing-tool-apk-signer/) to generate the key (.keystore) - this package serves, too , To sign and align the application; However, for that case I used **ONLY** to generate the key;
3. Go back to the Phone Gap, in the Android options, select 'add a key ...', then select your keystore generated in APK-Signer, and activate the rebuild;
4. Ready! Now just download the APK, go to google play and be happy.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem not so long ago it turned out to be an issue with @+id

A similar question has been asked before and got me through my problem, I will link the post as it is very informative.

[Android style Resources compile (aapt) failing : Bad resource table: header size 0xc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009618/android-style-resources-compile-aapt-failing-bad-resource-table-header-size)

Hope this helps you, wish you the best of luck.

Comment: Ctrl F "@+id" and see if you can find it, this may or not be the problem, I can only offer you my advice based on the information provided and my experience.  Best of luck.

Comment: Not it says "You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play"

I used xdaAutoAPKtool v4 to Zipalign this time

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to android too, and I had the same problem, and what worked for me was as simple as :

Zipalign the apk file by a tool called "Advanced APK tool" (download it from xda forum)

then reupload apk file to store without any problem detected,

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a latest version of aapt, from your Android SDK directory,

```
<Android_SDK_directory>/build-tools/<build_tools_version>/aapt
```